# Cisco Unified Presence Server - Update Lync Status value for In a Call

Tags: cisco, lync, unified-communications

The default value in Lync for a busy status is numerically represented as 6500. Is it possible to change the "In a call" status that the Cisco Unified Presence Server provides the Lync server.